# Releasing memory (if possible)

Tags: c++

Can I release the memory that was used to allocate the object? If so, how can I do it?

```
class CRectangle {
    int width, height;
public:
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {
        return (width * height);
    }
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
    width = a;
    height = b;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
    // Do something here
}
```

If i used dynamic memory allocation it will be:

```
   class CRectangle {
        int *width, *height;
    public:
        CRectangle (int,int);
        ~CRectangle ();
        int area () {
            return (*width * *height);
        }
    };

    CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
        width = new int;
        height = new int;
        *width = a;
        *height = b;

    }

    CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
        delete width
        delete height
    }
```

They do have same output, so what's the advantage of using dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: There is no memory allocation, other than the size of the object itself, in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular examples, both are technically correct and there is nothing more needed to be done in the destructor.

In the second example, there is absolutely no benefit, and it's in fact WASTING memory, because there is overhead in the allocation of memory. The smallest such overhead is 12 bytes + the allocation itself - in your case this is a total of 16 bytes if we assume `int` is 4 bytes (which is common, but there are alternatives).

Allocating objects is of benefit when the object varies in size (yours are always the size of one `int`) [and the largest size is larger than the expected overhead of allocating the memory itself] or of an object is optional [and larger than the expected overhead of allocating the object].

Imagine for example that we make your `CRectangle` hold a `CCell` object (for example, it may be the contents of each cell in a game of some sort) for every unit of size. Now if we also imagine that a rectangle can be any size from 1 x 1 to several thousand on each side, we wouldn't want to do a static two-dimensional array of several thousand in each dimension, right? So we would have to allocate it dynamically. For the purposes of this discussion, I'm just going to allocate a large array of `width * height`, because that's the size we need. One could consider doing a 2D allocation, but that makes the code more complex.

Here's what that would look like:

```
class CRectangle {
    int width, height;
    CCell* cellArray;
public:
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {
        return (width * height);
    }
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
    width = a;
    height = b;
    cellArray = new CCell[width * height];
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
    delete [] cellArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, no.All of your members are allocated *automatically* at the instantiation of the object. The only case you would have to worry freeing memory is in the case of a dynamic allocation(as automatic memory can not be freed until it falls out of scope). take for example these two ints:

```
int a; //automatic allocation at point of declaration, will exist until it falls out of scope
int *a = new int; //dynamic allocation, exists until deleted. Falling out of scope without releasing memory can cause a memory leak
```

---

Now if you're allocating your **objects** dynamically **then** you can free memory, but that is done outside of your class.

```
CRectangle *rect;
rect = new CRectangle; //dynamically allocated

//....

delete rect; //free memory allocated by rect
```

Comment: Is there any big differences between dynamically allocation and automatic allocation? Since both of them could reach the same output in this case?

Comment: memory wise, very different. object wise, it's just like an automatically allocated object. you might want to read up on dynamic allocation and it's uses: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: Really, you only have to worry about freeing memory if you're designing a smart pointer.  All the other code should just *use* smart pointers that already know when and how to free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the class you design, you need not do anything in the destructor.

this is OK:

```
CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
}
```

Comment: -1 incorrect. If someone creates objects at runtime via 'new' they always need to be deleted. In this case in the destructor.

Comment: @Rvdk: A class's destructor cannot delete itself.  That would cause infinite recursion.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the width and height created in CRectangle via new, they should be deleted in the destructor. The creation of CRectangle itself should be somewhere where it was created.

Comment: Ah but now you are talking about different things, there are two examples up there. Mou seems to be talking about the first example, RvdK about the second.